# How to remove specific html tags from a line in string?

Tags: php, replace

```
$find = '{<p>something</p>}';
$str1 = "<p>{<p>something</p>}</p>\r\ntext<p>something else</p>";
// or
$str2 = "<p>something</p>\r\n{<p>something</p>}aa<p>t</p>\r\ntext<p>something else</p>";
```

Basically, $find can be anywhere in the string. New lines delimiter is "\r\n".

I need to find $find in the $str and remove specific html tags around $find in that specific string line. No tags should be removed from $find.

Expected output would be

```
// For $str1
$str1 = "{<p>something</p>}\r\ntext<p>something else</p>";
// For $str2
$str2 = "<p>something</p>\r\n{<p>something</p>}aat\r\ntext<p>something else</p>";
```

The string might be very long, so no regex solutions please.

What I have figured out:

```
$pos = strpos($str, $find);
if ($pos !== false) {
    $contentLength = strlen($str);
    $lineStart = (int)strrpos($str, "\r\n", -$contentLength+$pos); // cast false to 0 (start of string)
    $lineEnd = strpos($str, "\r\n", $pos);
    if ($lineEnd === false)
        $lineEnd = strlen($str);

    $lineLength = $lineEnd-$lineStart;
    if ($lineLength < 0)
        return;

    var_dump(substr($str, $lineStart, $lineLength));
}
```

Which dumps that specific line in the string.

Comment: Can you give the tried code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution:

```
function replace($find, $str, $replace) {
    $pos = strpos($str, $find);
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $delim = "\r\n";
        $contentLength = strlen($str);

        $lineStart = strrpos($str, $delim, -$contentLength+$pos);
        if ($lineStart === false)
            $lineStart = 0;
        else
            $lineStart += strlen($delim);

        $lineEnd = strpos($str, $delim, $pos);
        if ($lineEnd === false)
            $lineEnd = strlen($str);

        $lineLength = $lineEnd - $lineStart;    

        $line = substr($str, $lineStart, $lineLength);
        $posLine = strpos($line, $find); // Where $find starts
        $findLength = strlen($find);

        $line = substr_replace($line, '', $posLine, $findLength); // Remove $find from $line
        $begin = replaceTags(substr($line, 0, $posLine));
        $end = replaceTags(substr($line, $posLine));

        return substr_replace($str, $begin.$replace.$end, $lineStart, $lineLength);
    }
}
function replaceTags($str) {
    return str_replace(array('<p>', '</p>'), '', $str);
}
echo replace($find, $str, $replace);
```